# i have create ontouch listenner, but when i run code i can not see my log. on touch event not run.please help. here is my code:

Tags: android

i have create ontouch listenner, but when i run code i can not see my log. on touch event not run.please help. here is my code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

private ImageView img;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    }   

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("test","test");
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:       
        Log.d("move down","move down"+X);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        Log.d("move x","move x"+X);
        Log.d("move y","move y"+Y);         
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you want event on imageview?

Comment: i don't see your interface listening to any object, what are you expecting?

Comment: here is my interface:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainscreen" >
   
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_senttext"/>

</RelativeLayout>
i want to move image around the screen

Answer (score 1):

If you want touch event on ImageView write

```
img.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null);
v.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: no, i want event to fire when i touch on screen. not on image

Answer (score 0):

A listener interlace is the bridge between the
',istener (you means your code) and event source (the ImageView or button or whatever you want).

if you want some event to occur you should create that bridge. your object will fire the event but you have to tell the object that you care about it by adding a listener to it

[image]

after implementing your interface to that object. that object will create an Event object which will fire your call back which you have implemented

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use any layout in xml.you do use unique id for layout in xml
then use this code in your class 
`YourLayout layout=(YourLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourlayoutid);
layout.setOnTouchListener(this)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {

        float sensitvity = 200;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if ((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity) {
         // Code for left swipe here
        }
        // **************** NOTHING ******************
        else if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity) {
         // Code for right swipe here
        }
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
};

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
        simpleOnGestureListener);
```

Comment: just use this code, no need to implement ontouch listener.  You can write code for left/right swipe here. It works fine for me :) :)